# Angular 2 router. Child route not activated in the 2rd time

Tags: angular, typescript

I have Angular 4.1.3 application with Angular 2 router. I used the following routes configuration:

```
export let ARTICLE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'article/:id', component: ArticleComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: ArticleContentComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: ':detailId', component: ArticleContentComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

And here is how I navigate between sections in the ArticleComponent:

```
<a [routerLink]="[section.id]">{{section.title}}</a>
```

When I click some section link the ArticleContentComponent is activated and re-rendered. When I click another link ArticleContentComponent not activated. Even its constructor is not invoked. No visible errors in the console.

I tried use programmatic navigation but it also doesn't work for the 2nd time:

```
this.router.navigate([sectionId], { relativeTo: this.route});
```

Please, advice.

Comment: After deep investigation I discovered that only way to detect route changes is to subscribe to route params. Even if ArticleContentComponent is not reloaded the route pushes new values: this.route.params.map(param => param.detailId).subscribe(item => this.handleSubArticle(item));

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe the activatedRoute parmeters like this

```
      this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(p => this.loadMovie(p["id"]));
```